# How to transfer my reputation from an unregistered account to a registered one?

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I used Stack Overflow for some time, but never registered. That account is here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/342369/b-i-d

Then I wanted to vote on an answer and learned that I have to register. So I made an account via openid using the same username and email. That one is here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/461711/b-i-d

Is there a way to get the reputation of my "old" account into the new one or do I have to work my way up the ladder again?

There should be an easier way to transfer an account from unregistered to registered.

Answer (score 1):

Great. AFTER writing this question there is a link with the answer in [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Answer: Write an email to team@stackoverflow.com

But the feature-request part is still valid: There should be an easier way, that doesn't require you to write emails to the team.

Comment: You could always flag one of your posts for moderator attention and explain in that. Site moderators (not necessarily SO employees) can also merge accounts.